# Generate.random.vector in R

Tags: r

cómo puede hacer que la suma de los valores de un vector de un número específico, en este caso sería `1`.

```
random.vector <- c((runif(1,0.2,0.4)),(runif(1,0.15,0.4)),(runif(1,0.15,0.3)),(runif(1,0.2,0.5)))
```

Necesito que la suma sea 1

Comment: Bienvenido Santiago a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿No puedes agregar un 5 elemento al vector que ajuste la diferencia a 1?

Answer (score 0):

Santiago creo que si no estás buscando que cada número en el vector este dentro de un rango y que sea a la vez positivo, podrías emplear lo siguiente para obtener 1:

```
randomVector <- randomVector/sum(randomVector)
```

Ya que si no fuera así, sería casi inmaterial conseguirse la suma de 1, por las propiedades que tiene la [distribución uniforme continua](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_continua).

> En el caso de las 4 funciones `runif` indicadas en este post inicial, si tomamos el caso límite `0.4+0.4+0.3+0.5>1` y el caso mínimo `0.2+0.15+0.15+0.2<1`, la `suma` estaría comprendida entre `[0.7, 1.6]`

Omití el punto en `random.vector` porque al parecer `.vector` es un método o función reservada por R, si quieres declarar variables largas en R, mi sugerencia es que emplees underline `_` o una práctica recomendada en programación: la notación [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

```
EjemploDeUpperCamelCase
ejemploDeLowerCamelCase
```

## Simulación de las sumas con las Distribuciones proporcionadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
"
randomVector <- c(
                  runif(1,0.2,0.4),
                  runif(1,0.15,0.4),
                  runif(1,0.15,0.3),
                  runif(1,0.2,0.5)
                  )
"

q<-1000 # longitud del vector

# vectores
v1<-runif(q,0.2,0.4)
v2<-runif(q,0.15,0.4)
v3<-runif(q,0.15,0.3)
v4<-runif(q,0.2,0.5)

# se crea el data.frame
df<-data.frame(v1=v1,v2=v2,v3=v3,v4=v4)

# se imprime los resultados
head(df); cat('\n')
summary(rowSums(df))

hist(rowSums(df))
```

Puedes acceder al código fuente aquí en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/FlusteredCheapQuote)

Comment: En este caso no era necesario emplear un bucle `for`